# Typescript select property

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Typescript. I want to select property

This is my observable

```
 entries:Observable<Log[]>;
```

Log class contains many properties like _id, name, etc. Now I want to get an array of string[] by extracting name out of the observable. How would I do that?

Is there any documentation available for this? I am finding this Typescript thing too tough IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you mean by `extracting name out of the observable`. If you want to extract all the property names into array of strings you can do it like this:

```
entries.subscribe((logs: Log[]) => {
   if (logs.length) {
      // extract all defined property names from first log
      let props = Object.keys(logs[0]);
      // do something with properties
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var source = entries.pluck('name').toArray();

var subscription = source.subscribe(names => {
  console.log(names);
});
```